# File chooser for vaadin web application

Tags: java, swing, vaadin

I am working on a vaadin web application. I want to have a JFileChooser type thing in my application by using which I would be able to get a path of a choosen file. I had used JFileChooser initially, but it only prompt on server computer, not on client. So I want the same thing for my client side on browser. 
Thanks.

Comment: Use a `form` based `<input type='file'..`.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use a [Upload component](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.upload.html) - see https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/other/upload for an example. There are also separate components in the Vaadin directory (e.g. https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/easyuploads)  might be more appropriate for your use-case.

It's important to note that you cannot control the appearance of the file browser at all - for example, you cannot point it to a particular directory, or limit the filter (e.g. specify *.doc). The "FileChooser" is completely in the control of the browser.

It *might* be possible to incorporate a third-party file upload widget into a Vaadin component, such as [SWFUpload](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/) or [JUpload](http://jupload.sourceforge.net/), but I have not seen any examples nor had any experience with doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the Vaadin version. 
I am working with Vaadin 8 and it is possible to restrict the filetype/mimetype.

```
Upload upload = new Upload();
upload.setAcceptMimeTypes("application/json");
```

Comment: why can't I see the method setAcceptMimeTypes when using vaadin 8?

Comment: You have to use the Upload plugin. It is not available in normal Button